# ui-router doesn't change browser url with default params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I actually have two problems.

Here is a state:

```
$stateProvider.state('detail', {
  url: '/detail?query',
  params: {query: 'abc'}
  templateUrl: 'views/detail.html',
  controller: 'DetailCtrl'
})
```

If I go to `/detail`, `$stateParams.query` is indeed set to `abc`. However, browser URL is still `/detail`, rather than `/detail?query=abc` (what we want).

What we currently do is call `$location.search('query', 'abc')` when `DetailCtrl` loads. However, when back button is clicked at `/detail?query=abc`, the browser goes back to `/detail`.

Expected behavior:

1. Go to `/detail`, browser should automatically set URL to `/detail?query=abc`.
2. Click back button at `/detail?query=abc`, browser should go back to the page before `/detail`.

Comment: which version of UI router are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.0.13 for Angular 1